# Content-Type was 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'

Tags: spring, gwt

I am trying to use Spring Security with GWT and I stumble over problems after problems because nothing seems to work like it actually should. At the moment I am trying to connect everything to my custom login page. For this I have a `FormPanel` which gets initialized like this:

```
public LoginViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    this.frmLogin.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    this.frmLogin.setAction("/app/login");
    this.frmLogin.setEncoding("text/x-gwt-rpc");

    this.txtUserID.setName("username");
    this.txtPassword.setName("password");
}
```

but as I click on the login button I am getting:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type was 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.checkContentTypeIgnoreCase(RPCServletUtils.java:477)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContent(RPCServletUtils.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsGwtRpc(RPCServletUtils.java:252)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.readContent(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:364)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    ...
```

I don't know how to avoid this. Any help is appreciated.

I also noticed that the `Content-Type` header of the request was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `text/x-gwt-rpc` like I've set it.

The HTML of this part says:

```
<form target="FormPanel_app_2" method="post" action="/app/login" enctype="text/x-gwt-rpc">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In GWT, `text/x-gwt-rpc` is used when GWT RPC is used as the server communication mode. In your example, you are submitting a normal HTML form (which is unaware of text/x-gwt-rpc as it is not a standard content type).

There are 2 options:

1. If you intend to use HTML form, you should be exposing a separate servlet to handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded form submission.
2. If you want to stick to GWT RPC, you can define some LoginService which captures username & password from fields and send the data to RPC servlet using GWT RPC semantics. (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html)

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response! I definitely would like to go with the easier and more straight forward solution here. I only need this kind of call for a spring security login action and nothing more. But which one would be the easier one here?

Answer (score -2):

Use RequestBuilder

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST,URL.encode(url));
builder.setHeader("Content-type", "text/x-gwt-rpc");
```